# Facebook Batch Request recognizing access token as user for page admin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, batch-processing

I am developing an app to post multiple post messages in one time. Say I have 5 fan pages and 10 groups. It will post them all. I have used graph api method and its working well when using for loop and executing one at a time. But I came to know about facebook batch request. Now the problem is when I to fan pages using fan page access token from (https://graph.facebook.com/100000598120816/accounts) its working fine

```
$param = array( 'message' => "Demo test " , 'access_token' => "<fan page access token>");
try { 
    $posted = $facebook->api('/425355934226513/feed/', 'post', $param);
    if (strlen($posted["id"]) > 0 ) $success = TRUE;
} catch  (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $errMsg = $e->getMessage();
    $error = TRUE;
}
```

But when I try to do the same using batch request, It post as the USER, not as PAGE ADMIN.

```
$arr1[] = array(  "method"=>"POST", 'relative_url' => '<fan page id>/feed',"body" => "message=Apps testing..Please ignore this message for page." , 'access_token' => "<FAN PAGE TOKEN>");
$arr1[] = array(  "method"=>"POST", 'relative_url' => '<my group id>/feed',"body" => "message=Apps testing..Please ignore this message for page." , 'access_token' => "<USER PAGE TOKEN>");
try { 
    $posted = $facebook->api("/?batch=".urlencode(json_encode($arr1)), 'post');
    $success = TRUE;
} catch  (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $errMsg = $e->getMessage();
    $error = TRUE;

}
```

P.S Both the above code runs successfully. But in fan page its showing as the USER not PAGE ADMIN.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that only Users can post to groups, not Pages. It works that way even manually posting to groups.

Answer (score 0):

You should try specifying a "fallback" Access Token as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/#differentaccesstokens This Access Token should be an App Access Token.

Also, I'm not sure if you're not overwriting your `$arr1[]` variable...

Comment: Hi. the fb document suggest 
'batch=[{ "method":"POST","relative_url":"me/feed","body":"message=Test status update&link=http://developers.facebook.com/"},{ "method":"GET","relative_url":"me/feed?limit=1"}]'

And i am giving both separate access token.. How can i get out of this situation now. If this things not work then i have to loop over pages again and again instead of using batch.

Comment: Any one with other suggestion. please help

Answer (score 0):

try 'relative_url' => '/feed?access_token=' and the same for the group/user token.

There is a bug that doesn't look for the access_token in the json, even though the documentation states it is allowed.